# How do I reduce dependencies in my bloated WPF MainWindow?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I'm developing a large WPF application and most of the functionality resides in just one window. I use Autofac for DI and I try to keep to the MVVM pattern. I used a ViewModel, until one wasn't enough. I then separated into a number of ViewModels. Then helper objects appeared, new windows to which I tied events, and so forth.

My MainWindow now has a constructor that looks something like this:

```
public MainWindow(
        IConnectionViewModel connectionViewModel, 
        IFilterViewModel filterViewModel, 
        IAnotherViewModel anotherViewModel, 
        IPipeline pipeline, 
        IWorkingScreens workingScreens, 
        IClientSideConnectionManager clientSideConnectionManager, 
        IYetAnotherViewModel yetAnotherViewModel, 
        IDialogViewModel dialogViewModel, 
        IDialogViewModel2 dialogViewModel2,  
        IDetailWindow detailWindow,
        IAnotherWindow anotherWindow,
        IApplicationController applicationController
        )
        : base(workingScreens)
```

What is perhaps worse is that this file is over 300 lines long! Before I add yet another dependency to this monstrosity, can someone give me an idea of what refactoring needs to be done? What abstraction(s) am I missing?

Comment: OMG what in the world is that? Constructors with 3+ parameters are bad, no matter what. Parameterized constructors for the VIEW are even worse. Why do you need all that in the window? Also, use MEF or otherwise change the constructor injector for automatic injection somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're not really using the MVVM pattern if you have that many dependencies in your `MainWindow`. With an IoC container and your `MainWindow` in MVVM, you should be injecting only the `MainWindow`s ViewModel Class, setting its DataContext to that created class.

The constructor of the ViewModel, or some task which builds your data model and supplies it to the VM, would handle the rest of the construction.

If your MainWindow XAML is very complex, consider compartmentalizing the UI elements into `UserControl`s, `ContentControl` snippets, or Custom Controls,  which you can associate with ViewModels focused on only presenting the UI of a specific bit of functionality. This will give you class-level control over UI elements whose concerns are separated. If I were to use that kind of approach, then I would expose different ViewModel classes as properties in my MainWindow VM, and set the sub-elements' `DataContext` to those properties using "`{Binding SomeProperty}`" syntax.

When architecting for WPF I usually try to start with a one-to-one-to-one relationship between View, ViewModel, and Model classes initially, refactoring common elements into base classes if it will help. This breaks complex UI problems down very nicely, but introduces problems if you need to communicate between model or ViewModel classes.

To solve that, I turned to the Prism message passing publish and subscribe patterns, using `CompositePresentationEvent` class definitions in App.xaml to get around all that separation in the few places I needed it. It's easy to use those without making use of any other part of the Prism library, and you can certainly use other message passers if you don't want Prism-bloat in your runtimes.

Comment: I particularly like what you said about compartmentalizing. I will try this out and see if I can reduce the complexity. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No one can really help you but yourself, i am saying this because the only way to refactor this anti-pattern which is called [Constructor Over-Injection](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/constructor-over-injection-anti-pattern/) and which *- by the way -* is a symptom of violation of the (SRP) [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), the only way is to find commonalities between those dependencies and group related ones into their own class.

For example i can see `IDialogViewModel`, `IDialogViewModel2` which seem pretty related to me.
`IAnotherViewModel` and `IYetAnotherViewModel` seem like candidates too and so on and so on.

Grouping those dependencies into other classes will reduce the number of parameters and will let you move some of those 300+ lines of code to where they really belong which on the long run should also help with the SRP.